# Checked and change radio button in one group name

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I have a table that has a radio button with the same "name" attribute as a row selector in each row.
There is simple JQuery code that selects the checked radio button and finds the `<tr>` tag and then highlights it by css, the problem is: when I change the radio button from another table row's, new rows gets the style but previous row are still highlighted! here is my HTML:

```js
$('.my-table input').click(function() {
    var checked = $(this).attr('checked', true);
    if (checked) {
        $(this).closest('tr').addClass("highlighted");
    } else {
        $(this).closest('tr').removeClass("highlighted");
    }
});
```

```css
.highlighted {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="my-table">
  <thead class="my-table-head">
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>
          <input class="with-gap" name="group1" type="radio" id="rbtn2">
          <label for="rbtn2"></label>
        </p>
      </td>
      <td>title</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>
          <input class="with-gap" name="group1" type="radio" id="rbtn3">
          <label for="rbtn3"></label>
        </p>
      </td>
      <td>titke2</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>
          <input class="with-gap" name="group1" type="radio" id="rbtn4">
          <label for="rbtn4"></label>
        </p>
      </td>
      <td>title3</td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('.my-table input').click(function() {
        $(this).closest('tbody').find('tr').removeClass("highlighted");
        $(this).closest('tr').addClass("highlighted");
});
```

```css
.highlighted {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="my-table">
  <thead class="my-table-head">
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>
          <input class="with-gap" name="group1" type="radio" id="rbtn2">
          <label for="rbtn2"></label>
        </p>
      </td>
      <td>title</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>
          <input class="with-gap" name="group1" type="radio" id="rbtn3">
          <label for="rbtn3"></label>
        </p>
      </td>
      <td>titke2</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>
          <input class="with-gap" name="group1" type="radio" id="rbtn4">
          <label for="rbtn4"></label>
        </p>
      </td>
      <td>title3</td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

It better to use change event instead of click event. Remove class `highlighted` from all `tr` in the very first of change event like follownig.

```js
$('.my-table input').change(function() {
    $('.my-table tr').removeClass("highlighted");      
    if (this.checked) {
        $(this).closest('tr').addClass("highlighted");
    }
});
```

```css
.highlighted {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="my-table">
  <thead class="my-table-head">
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>
          <input class="with-gap" name="group1" type="radio" id="rbtn2">
          <label for="rbtn2"></label>
        </p>
      </td>
      <td>title</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>
          <input class="with-gap" name="group1" type="radio" id="rbtn3">
          <label for="rbtn3"></label>
        </p>
      </td>
      <td>titke2</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>
          <input class="with-gap" name="group1" type="radio" id="rbtn4">
          <label for="rbtn4"></label>
        </p>
      </td>
      <td>title3</td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

removing the class "highlighted" of the all tr tag in the document is a quickly way to do it.

```js
    $('.my-table input').click(function() {
      $('tr').removeClass("highlighted")
      var checked = $(this).attr('checked', true);
      if (checked) {
        $(this).closest('tr').addClass("highlighted");
      }
    });
```

```css
.highlighted {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="my-table">
  <thead class="my-table-head">
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>
          <input class="with-gap" name="group1" type="radio" id="rbtn2">
          <label for="rbtn2"></label>
        </p>
      </td>
      <td>title</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>
          <input class="with-gap" name="group1" type="radio" id="rbtn3">
          <label for="rbtn3"></label>
        </p>
      </td>
      <td>titke2</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>
          <input class="with-gap" name="group1" type="radio" id="rbtn4">
          <label for="rbtn4"></label>
        </p>
      </td>
      <td>title3</td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove class `highlighted` before adding the class.

Do like Below:

```
 $('.my-table input').click(function() {
    var checked = $(this).attr('checked', true);
    $('.my-table').find('.highlighted').removeClass('highlighted');
    if (checked) {
        $(this).closest('tr').addClass("highlighted");
    }
});
```

**DEMO:** [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gbbof6bf/)